# How to add CastButton to MaterialToolbar (not appcompat Toolbar)

Tags: kotlin, google-cast

I am trying to implement CastSdk to app in which I use MaterialToolbar.

So after couple tries to add CastButton to my material toolbar I finally end up with a button on it but greyed out...

At first I thought it is because wrong receiver app id, maybe a problem in manifest file. But it turned out that the problem is with MaterialToolbar.
Migrating to appcompat toolbar fixes this problem, but what if I don't want to migrate to it from materialToolbar?

Code with greyed out button on materialToolbar:

In MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.top_app_bar, menu)
    val mediaRouteItem: MenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item)
    val mMediaRouteButton = mediaRouteItem.actionView as MediaRouteButton

    CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(applicationContext, mMediaRouteButton)
    return true
}
```

In Menu xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
    app:actionProviderClass="androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

In OptionsProvider implementation:

```
override fun getCastOptions(context: Context): CastOptions {
    val launchOptions: LaunchOptions = LaunchOptions.Builder()
        .setAndroidReceiverCompatible(true)
        .build()
    return CastOptions.Builder()
        .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id))
        .setLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        .build()
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answer here is pretty simple:
Except of putting the castButton inside menu.xml file, place it right inside the MaterialToolbar layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/app_bar_background"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:liftOnScroll="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_24"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:logo="@drawable/rick_morty_icon"
        app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end">

            <androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton
                android:id="@+id/media_route_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:mediaRouteTypes="user"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

then in the Activity in onCreate method:

```
val mMediaRouteButton = findViewById<View>(R.id.media_route_button) as MediaRouteButton
    CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(applicationContext, mMediaRouteButton)
```

or if you use viewBinding:

```
CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(applicationContext, binding.mediaRouteButton)
```